Vorrei ringraziare la comunità di questo sito
Buonasera,
Vorrei ringraziare la comunità di questo sito per l'aiuto che mi avete prestato su qualche difficoltà in Il fu Mattia Pascal di Luigi Pirandello. Molti anni fa, mi è venuta l'idea che non ci fosse una buona traduzione di questo bellissimo romanzo in russo. Credevo infatti di intravedere già che cosa rendesse così bello questo romanzo, e volevo, con il mio amore per la lingua russa e per la letteratura russa, tentare di tradurlo da me. Ho lavorato per anni, ho imparato moltissimo sul mestiere molto difficile di traduttore, ho messo molto tempo a osservare minuziosamente "l'organizzazione interna" del romanzo, ho fatto una traduzione amatoriale per tutti. Non posso giudicare il mio lavoro da me stesso, eppure vorrei sottolineare che mi avete aiutato moltissimo, molte grazie! Spero di non essere andato contro le norme di questo sito.
